# LibHaru: How to draw a line of exact one inch

Tags: printing, dpi, printers, libharu

Following is the code snippet I used to print a  line of length 1 inch with the default DPI  level(72dpi ).

page.moveTo(5, 20);
page.lineTo(72, 20);

But when I take the printout, line is smaller than 1 inch. (around 2.24 cm instead of 2.54cm)

Comment: have you figured it out?

Comment: Does your print scale the output to fit on the printable part of the paper?